# Bootstrap toast not shown on click (Angular)

Tags: angular, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to show a simple Toast on click by following this [documentation](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/toast/examples)

After i've created the service

import { Injectable, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ToastService {
  toasts: any[] = [];

  show(textOrTpl: string | TemplateRef<any>, options: any = {}): any {
    this.toasts.push({ textOrTpl, ...options });
  }

    remove(toast: any): any {
    this.toasts = this.toasts.filter(t => t !== toast);
  }
}
```

I'm trying to call the `toast` from a modal `(click)` that is inside my `negozio.component`

it looks like this:

```
     ...
    <button
      type="button"
      class="btn btn-success"
      (click)="showToast(addedToast)"
    >
      Aggiungi al carrello
    </button>
  </div>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #addedToast>
  <i class="material-icons">check_circle_outline</i>
  {{ modalContent.desc }} Aggiunto
</ng-template>
```

And my showToast function looks like this:

```
  showToast(toast: any): void {
    this.toastService.show(toast, { classname: 'bg-success text-light', delay: 15000 });
  }
```

But it doesn't have any effect, no toast is shown, but the on click method is called as if i put an alert inside `showToast()` it will be shown...

Comment: Please check this:
https://therichpost.com/angular-10-bootstrap-toast-working-example/

Answer (score 0):

Rather than implementing your own ToastrService, you can just use ngx-toastr. https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-toastr

Demo: https://ngx-toastr.vercel.app/

Sample Usage:

```
export class YourComponent {
  constructor(private toastr: ToastrService) {}
 
  showSuccess() {
    this.toastr.success('Hello world!', 'Toastr fun!');
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I Was trying to paste above code inside component.module.ts which leads to this error. after moving to app.module.ts worked for me.